# What does "smaller" mean for multiple references that share a lifetime specifier?

Tags: rust

[*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html) says:

> ```rust
> fn longest<'a>(x: &'a str, y: &'a str) -> &'a str {
>     if x.len() > y.len() {
>         x
>     } else {
>         y
>     }
> }
> ```

> The function signature now tells Rust that for some lifetime `'a`, the
> function takes two parameters, both of which are string slices that
> live at least as long as lifetime `'a`. The function signature also
> tells Rust that the string slice returned from the function will live
> at least as long as lifetime `'a`. In practice, it means that the
> lifetime of the reference returned by the `longest` function is the
> same as the smaller of the lifetimes of the references passed in.
> These relationships are what we want Rust to use when analyzing this
> code.

I don't get why it says:

> In practice, it means that the lifetime of the reference returned by
> the `longest` function is the same as the smaller of the lifetimes of
> the references passed in.

Note the word "smaller". For both parameters and returned values, we specified `'a` which is the same. Why does the book say "smaller"? If that was the case, we would have different specifiers(`a'`, `b'`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Semantics of lifetime parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67802520/semantics-of-lifetime-parameters)

Answer (score 4):

It's important to note that in the example, whatever is passed as `x` and `y` do not have to have **identical** lifetimes.

Let's rework the example to use `&i32` which makes for easier demonstrations:

```
fn biggest<'a>(x: &'a i32, y: &'a i32) -> &'a i32 {
    if x > y {
        x
    } else {
        y
    }
}
```

Now, given the following example:

```
fn main() {
    let bigger;
    let a = 64;

    {
        let b = 32;
        bigger = biggest(&a, &b);
    }

    dbg!(bigger);
}
```

We have 3 different lifetimes:

- `bigger` which lives until the end of `main`
- `a` which lives until the end of `main`
- `b` which lives until the end of its block

Now lets take the description apart

> the lifetime of the reference returned by the [...] function

In our case this would be `bigger`, which lives until the end of `main`

> smaller of the lifetimes of the references passed in

We passed in `a`, which gets dropped at the end of `main`, and `b`, which gets dropped at the end of its block. Since `b` gets dropped first, it is the "smaller" lifetime.

And sure enough, the compiler yells at us:

```
error[E0597]: `b` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:7:30
   |
7  |         bigger = biggest(&a, &b);
   |                              ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
8  |     }
   |     - `b` dropped here while still borrowed
9  |
10 |     dbg!(bigger);
   |          ------ borrow later used here
```

But if we move `bigger` inside the block, and hence reduce its lifetime, the code compiles:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 64;

    {
        let b = 32;
        let bigger = biggest(&a, &b);
        dbg!(bigger);
    }

    println!("This works!");
}
```

Now `a` and `b` still have different lifetimes but the code compiles since the the smaller of both lifetimes (`b`'s) is the same as `bigger`'s lifetime.

Did this help illustrate what "smaller" lifetime means?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. really appreciate. My biggest misunderstanding is that since both parameters and return value have the same specifier(`a'`) , why and how does rust check and decide that it's gonna make sure that returned value's lifetime is the smaller of the passed arguments' specifiers ?

Comment: More importantly, if we hadn't specified `a'` specifiers for all of them, why wouldn't rust figure this out on its own for this specific example of yours ?

Comment: Rust mentions that if we hadn't specified specifiers, it would think: `The help text reveals that the return type needs a generic lifetime parameter on it because Rust can’t tell whether the reference being returned refers to x or y. `. To be honest, I am not sure how specifying the same lifetime specifier solves the fact that rust knows at compile time which reference the function returns(x or y)

Comment: @NikaKurashvili [Why are explicit lifetimes needed in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31609137/155423)