# What exactly happens when specifying multiple references with the same lifetime?

Tags: rust

A lot of tutorials use the following example to explain lifetime (including the [official one](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/first-edition/lifetimes.html#multiple-lifetimes)), but I don't think any of them really explain what happens behind the scene.

```
fn x_or_y<'a>(x: &'a str, y: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    if x.len() > y.len() {
        x
    }
    else {
        y
    }
}
```

The [official tutorial](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/first-edition/lifetimes.html#multiple-lifetimes) says:

> This says that x and y both are alive for the same scope, and that the
> return value is also alive for that scope.

But why **x and y both are alive for the same scope**?

If I destroy `x` right after calling this function but leave `y` alone, then `x` lives **shorter** than `y`.

How are they alive for the same scope? I think this statement is simply wrong.

Or, does it mean that it is the programmer's responsibility to make sure parameters with the same lifetime specifiers must have the same lifetime?

But if this is the case, why does the compiler allow parameters with different lifetimes to have the same specifier? Why doesn't it check it for us?

For example, in the following code, `x` and `y` have different lifetimes, but I can give them both the specifier of `'a`:

```
    // This does NOT compile.
    let x = String::from("abcd");
    let y = String::from("abc");
    let result = x_or_y(x.as_str(), y.as_str());
    drop(y); // y's lifetime ends here, which is shorter than that of x.
    println!("result = {}", result);
    println!("x = {}", x); // x's lifetime ends here, which is longer than that of y.
```

This gives the following compilation error, but not because of lifetime specifier is not consistent with parameters' lifetime, but something else:

```
3 |     let y = String::from("abc");
  |         - binding `y` declared here
4 |     let result = x_or_y(x.as_str(), y.as_str());
  |                                     - borrow of `y` occurs here
5 |     drop(y);
  |          ^ move out of `y` occurs here
6 |     println!("result = {}", result);
  |                             ------ borrow later used here
```

Since this is compile time and the code hasn't been run yet, so the compiler **doesn't know** which of `x` and `y` will be returned (it is `x` actually because its length is bigger, therefore in runtime there shouldn't be any bug because `x` is still valid when `result` is being printed).

However, compiler knows exactly that it is `y` who caused the problem.

How is it possible? I think it can only be because that compiler figured it out based on the returned value `result`'s lifetime.

In other words, `result`'s lifetime can only possibly be the same as that of `y` but not that of `x`, because only y's is shorter and will cause problems. `x`'s will be fine.

In other words, we specified the lifetime of `x` and `y` to be both `'a` (though they are different, `x` is longer than `y`), but compiler actually assigned the lifetime of `y` (the shorter one) to the returned value `result`, not that of `x` (the longer one).

Only in this way the compiler can figure out the error shown above.

With that said, my guess about the mechanism behind lifetime is:
after specifying the 2 parameters and the returned value with the same lifetime (`'a` in this case), the compiler does the following 2 steps **behind the scene**:

1. Get the shortest lifetime of `x` and `y`, which is like an operation of `desired_life_time = min(x_lifetime, y_lifetime)`.
2. Give `desired_life_time` to the returned value `&'a str`.

I wonder if this is correct?

**Supplement**:

Another [official tutorial](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-annotations-in-function-signatures) says

> In practice, it means that the lifetime of the reference returned by the `longest` function is the same as the smaller of the lifetimes of the values referred to by the function arguments.

This seems to confirm my guess above, but the syntax of lifetime specifier is still very confusing:

the two parameters are labelled with the **same** lifetime specifier, `'a`, but their lifetimes are **different**, one is smaller than the other?

If their lifetimes are **different**, why do we use the **same** specifier `'a` on them?

Comment: "If I destroy x right after calling this function" - have you tried doing that? Did the compiler allow it?

Comment: @Grismar Yes, the compiler allows it IF the returned value `result` is not used afterwards. Otherwise, it doesn't allow it. My question is, in the former case, what is the lifetime of `result`? Is it the same as `x` or `y` (`x` is longer than `y`)?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67816688/5397009

Comment: The answer is that "the same lifetime" doesn't mean identical scope in the caller. As long as the compiler can find a lifetime that is valid for both scopes in the caller, it will go ahead and use it. In other words, your guess is correct.

Answer (score 6):

> If I destroy `x` right after calling this function but leave `y` alone, then `x` lives shorter than `y`.
>
> How are they alive for the same scope?

First of all, note that within `x_or_y()`, `x` and `y` are variables **containing references** — they are not their referents. This is an important distinction to make when you want to think carefully about lifetimes, because there are actually three different scopes or time-spans when we talk about some `&'a T`:

1. The time when the reference is being used and before it is dropped, which must be no longer than
2. the time meant by the lifetime `'a`, which must be no longer than
3. the time within which the particular value of type `T` is a valid value in that memory location, and not being mutated.

**These are all potentially different times**.

When you borrow the contents of a `String`, you get a reference with a new lifetime `&'b str`, but `'b` does not mean the entire period for which the `String` exists — rather, it means the period *for which you are borrowing the `String` this time*, which can flex longer or shorter as needed. `'b` is constrained to be longer when you make use of the reference for longer, or constrain the lifetime to be the same as or outlive some other lifetime, and `'b` is constrained to be shorter when you drop, move, or mutate the `String` (`'b` must end before that happens).

In general, borrow errors happen when "this lifetime must be this long" constraints and "this lifetime must be this short" constraints conflict with each other; if there is no conflict, there is no error.

However, many of these constraints can cooperate because of a particular principle: it is always sound to take a reference with a long lifetime and *treat it as if* it has a shorter lifetime, and Rust's type system has a “coercion” rule that says this is permitted. (In theoretical terms, we can say that references are “covariant over their lifetime”.) That's why the call to `x_or_y(x.as_str(), y.as_str())` succeeds; the longer-lived reference is coerced to have the same lifetime as the shorter-lived one.

> …my guess about the mechanism behind lifetime is:  after specifying
> the 2 parameters and the returned value with the same lifetime (`'a`
> in this case), the compiler does the following 2 steps **behind the
> scene**:
>
> 1. Get the shortest lifetime of `x` and `y`, which is like an operation of `desired_life_time = min(x_lifetime, y_lifetime)`.
> 2. Give `desired_life_time` to the returned value `&'a str`.

You've got the right general idea, but you've applied it in the wrong spot. It's not that the function's input lifetimes are actually different, it's that **before `x_or_y()` is called**, inside of the function that's calling it, the two reference arguments are coerced so that their lifetime is `min(x_lifetime, y_lifetime)`. So, within the function definition, `'a` *really is just one lifetime* (per call), but for this particular call to the function, that lifetime `'a` is `min(x_lifetime, y_lifetime)`. The adjustment happens implicitly in the code surrounding the function call, not within the function.

---

Tangential stuff; ignore this if it doesn't make sense:

In general, the borrow-checker is a constraint solver, so it's not really even computing `min(x_lifetime, y_lifetime)`; rather, it has a set of constraints about how long lifetimes are, like `'a <= 'x && 'a <= 'y`, and it looks to see that these don't conflict with each other. As long as they don't, it's happy to approve your program; `'a` doesn't even ever really get a concrete “lifetime value” assigned to it. There is no single time at which a lifetime truly ends; only constraints on the earliest it could end (last use of the reference) and the latest (drop, move, or mutation of the referent).