# What is the significance of lifetime annotations in Rust?

Tags: rust

Can the lifetime parameter in Rust be understood as a syntax specification introduced to reduce the cost of compile-time static checking?

If not, what other roles does it play?

I have tried to compile this code:

```
struct RefHolder<T> {
    m: T,
}
fn main() {
    let holder;
    {
        let hello = String::from("hello");
        holder = RefHolder {
            m: &hello
        };
    }
}
```

It can be compiled. But this can't because of the missing lifetime parameter:

```
struct RefHolder<T> {
    m: &T,
}
fn main() {
    let holder;
    {
        let hello = String::from("hello");
        holder = RefHolder {
            m: &hello
        };
    }
}
```

It seems that the compiler is lazier when it sees the following code. I was wondering if someone could explain it in detail.

Comment: Lifetimes must be specified when they are part of an interface, because the compiler only works locally, and needs some way to communicate lifetime constraints between locations. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67816688/5397009) about lifetimes in function parameters, the same idea applies to `struct` definitions since the `struct` may at some point be passed or returned between functions.

Comment: Not just reduce the cost, in fact to make it feasible.

Comment: In this example, however, the compiler could infer the lifetime, and in fact there was a discussion about that (but it was decided that no).

Answer (score 1):

I won't explain what lifetimes are in general: besides [Jmb's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78015566/what-is-the-significance-of-lifetime-annotations-in-rust#comment137536982_78015566) there is plenty of existing reference material, such as the Rust Book, e.g. its section on [References and borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html).

But regarding your concrete code examples:

> It seems that the compiler is lazier when it sees the following code.

The compiler is really given a different task here. When you write `&T` as in the second case, the compiler cannot simply instantiate `T` as `'a str`—the reference type always includes a lifetime, even if it is often hidden (and inferred) or unnameable in concrete syntax.

So, in the second case, you are really declaring a struct that looks like this:

```rust
struct RefHolder<T> {
    m: &'_ T, // some lifetime must go here
}
```

This is not solvable. When considering the `struct` declaration by itself, there is no lifetime to use. The only lifetime that *could* be used is `'static`, but this would be surprising to users and generally not what you want in a `struct` that holds a reference. So, the compiler instead refuses to accept the type declaration, prompting the programmer to be more specific with the lifetimes.

(Why could the lifetime not come from `T`? As declared, `T` could be anything. For example, it could be an `i32`: there is no lifetime to take from such a type.)

In the first case, the struct ends up looking very similar to the second case, but the compiler does not refuse it. This is because all the lifetime information comes from the function where `RefHolder` is being instantiated and used. `T` is instantiated as `&'a str`, where `'a` corresponds to the lifetime of the `hello` variable—but again, notice that this lifetime does not make sense outside of the function where `hello` is declared.

Although it seems like the first case is solving what the second case does not, there are other consequences if `RefHolder` were to be used elsewhere. This links to the idea of [parametricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametricity), i.e. that when using `RefHolder<T>` with `T` being a completely unconstrained type parameter (as declared in the first case), the code should not be able to make any assumptions about `T` at all. In other words, if the function `fn foo<T>(x: RefHolder<T>) { ... }` compiles, then it should not result in a runtime type error no matter what `T` is chosen.

As a result, in the first case, any such `foo` function would not be able to do much with the `m` field. In particular, it could not assume that `m` is a reference. In the second case (if properly fixed by adding a lifetime parameter to the struct declaration and using it for the reference), `foo` would know that the `m` field must hold a reference, and it would know its lifetime. However, it could not make any assumptions about what is contained in the reference, again because it would be the generic `T` type.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! On a more theoretical note, do lifecycle parameters reduce the complexity of the "avoiding dangling references" issue to an acceptable level (or perhaps transform it from an undecidable problem into a decidable one)? Are there any related theoretical studies on this topic?

Comment: @youzheyin The primary need for lifetimes is (AFAIU) modularity: to be able to compile crates without knowing about every other function or crate in the entire project. Declaring lifetimes on functions draws boundaries: when compiling the function, we need to consider *any* lifetime (that satisfies the declared constraints); when compiling callsites, we know only as much about the function as its signature (incl. lifetimes) tells us. You could imagine a version of the compiler that more aggressively inlines methods: it might need fewer annotations, but it would be slower and less predictable.

Comment: In the literature, you can see the need for such abstraction already in various heap analyses (see e.g. [here](https://doi.org/10.1145/2931098)): that is, *summarising* what pointers/fields might point to into regions rather than individual (symbolic) objects. The concept of ownership is also not unique to Rust, and has a lot of parallels with e.g. separation logic (as demonstrated by the [Prusti project](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-031-06773-0_5)). There are attempts and works in progress trying to underpin the system formally, see e.g. [here](https://doi.org/10.1145/3443420).