Why do we need to tell compiler the lifetime when it can detect problematic lifetime on its own?
I am learning the concept of Lifetime from the Brown Rust Book.
And I first thought the compiler needs lifetime because it couldn't tell
the lifetime of references without it so as programmers we need to tell it.
However, in one example of the book, it gives some code that cannot be compiled
because the compiler found the lifetime was not correct.
So my question is, in this case, the compiler definitely can find an incorrect lifetime
and even tell me how to fix it. Doesn't this mean the complier definitely knows the lifetime of the references that involved in this function. In this sense, why do programmers bother to add lifetime in the function signature ?
The example and compiler output:
fn shortest<'a, 'b>(x: &'a str, y: &'b str) -> &'a str {
  if x.len() < y.len() {
    x
  } else {
    y
  }
}
fn main() {
  println!("{}", shortest("hello", "rust"));
}

  |
1 | fn shortest<'a, 'b>(x: &'a str, y: &'b str) -> &'a str {
  |             --  -- lifetime `'b` defined here
  |             |
  |             lifetime `'a` defined here
...
5 |     y
  |     ^ function was supposed to return data with lifetime `'a` but it is returning data with lifetime `'b`
  |
  = help: consider adding the following bound: `'b: 'a`


Because the compiler does not know which lifetimes x and y are supposed to have. If you assign them different lifetime parameters 'a and 'b and return a reference with lifetime 'a from the function, the compiler can in this case infer, that 'b: 'a, so it tells you to to add this necessary constraint. However, you can also tell the compiler, that you expect x and y to have the same lifetime: Playground

We as programmers provide lifetime annotations to assert our intent, and the compiler verifies that our code does not violate those assertions.  When the compiler detects a violation, it could either be because the lifetime annotation is wrong, or because the code is wrong: the compiler doesn't know which.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67816688/5397009


So my question is, in this case, the compiler definitely can find an incorrect lifetime [...] Doesn't this mean the complier definitely knows the lifetime of the references that involved in this function. In this sense, why do programmers bother to add lifetime in the function signature ?

Finding if a given solution to an equation is correct is much easier than solving it. In other words, the compiler being able to verify your lifetime annotations does not mean it can make them for you.

...and even tell me how to fix it

Now, this is a correct question. And it has three answers.

Performance. If the compiler will have to analyze your whole code to determine its lifetimes, it will be a lot slower (this is somewhat an antidote to the next reason: it explain why the compiler cannot do that locally (i.e. by analyzing one function each time), this one explains why it cannot do it globally (i.e. by analyzing all functions together).

Accuracy. The compiler suggestions as good enough as suggestions, and even there they can still improve, but they are nowhere nere able to replace the borrow checker. In this simple example they are correct, but in more complex snippets they quickly get confused. Bugs are filled almost every day. They are nice-to-improve-quality-of-life issues when it comes to diagnostics, but they will deal breaker if the compiler would only use them.
Even worse, the compiler diagnostics are so good because they have the information you give the compiler to rely on. If the compiler would have to infer it all by itself, it would be much less accurate.
As a subreason, we like language rules to be simple, because this way they can be easily understood. Cross-function lifetime inference is everything but simple to understand.

Readability. Rust made an explicit decision to make a clear boundary: inside a function, a lot is inferred (not just lifetimes, but also types for example). But outside of functions, when defining the API boundary, everything must be explicit (there are few exceptions to that but most parts of the language abide to this rule). This helps the compiler, but it helps the programmer not less. When you see a function in Rust, you immediately know its type and lifetime requirements, and that serves as documentation and helps clarify the intent.



Finding if a given solution to an equation is correct is much easier than solving it. So you proved that P != NP? :-D

@RichardNeumann No, I proved that we don't know if P=NP.
